# why does GPG ignore the trust level I had set for recepient key?

Tags: encryption, public-key, gpg

I encountered the following puzzling behavior with `GPG`: after I set trust for a recipient's key, gpg still complains it doesn't know if it should use the encryption subkey and prompts for input.

Here are the individual steps:

### create my own keypair

I only include this step here because otherwise gpg complains that it can't find a key with ultimate trust, which I suppose is then used to sign the trustdb.

```
$ gpg --genkey
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.7; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

[...]

pub   ed25519 2023-12-02 [SC] [expires: 2025-12-01]
      BDCCA3DA3E0961575FC797B66E51892F600D443B
uid                      Testy Testerson <testy@example.net>
sub   cv25519 2023-12-02 [E] [expires: 2025-12-01]
```

#### Import recipient's key

```
gpg --import ~/tmp/fiend.pubkey
gpg: key 7507E17705538C1C: public key "Friend of Testy Testerson <friendoftesty@example.net>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

#### Assign 'full' trust to the imported key:

```
$ gpg-edit-key $(gpg --list-keys | grep DF57EKDF57E)
[...]
pub  ed25519/7507E17705538C1C
     created: 2023-12-02  expires: 2025-12-01  usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  cv25519/F2FA4C3E9932F093
     created: 2023-12-02  expires: 2025-12-01  usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Friend of Testy Testerson <friendoftesty@example.net>

gpg> trust
pub  ed25519/7507E17705538C1C
     created: 2023-12-02  expires: 2025-12-01  usage: SC
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  cv25519/F2FA4C3E9932F093
     created: 2023-12-02  expires: 2025-12-01  usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Friend of Testy Testerson <friendoftesty@example.net>

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 4

pub  ed25519/7507E17705538C1C
     created: 2023-12-02  expires: 2025-12-01  usage: SC 
     trust: full          validity: ultimate
sub  cv25519/F2FA4C3E9932F093
     created: 2023-12-02  expires: 2025-12-01  usage: E
[ultimate] (1). Friend of Testy Testerson <friendoftesty@example.net>

gpg> save
Key not changed so no update needed.
```

#### Verify that `trustdb` was updated correctly:

```
$ gpg --export-ownertrust
# List of assigned trustvalues, created Sat Dec  2 14:27:26 2023 MST
# (Use "gpg --import-ownertrust" to restore them)

BDCCA3DA3E0961575FC797B66E51892F600D443B:6:
DF57E983DFD9EFA53DF3C0CD7507E17705538C1C:5:
```

#### Try using the recipient key for encryption

This is the clincher: I expected gpg to know the level of trust at this point and not to put up such a fuss:

```
$ gpg -e --recipient $(gpg --list-keys | grep DF57E) --output ./test.gpg ./test

gpg: F2FA4C3E9932F093: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user

sub  cv25519/F2FA4C3E9932F093 2023-12-02 Friend of Testy Testerson <friendoftesty@example.net>
 Primary key fingerprint: DF57 E983 DFD9 EFA5 3DF3  C0CD 7507 E177 0553 8C1C
      Subkey fingerprint: CD16 DC41 E806 92A1 1590  A0EB F2FA 4C3E 9932 F093

It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named
in the user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing,
you may answer the next question with yes.

Use this key anyway? (y/N) n
```

##### My question: What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Similar issue for me. Does this command printout the trust level for each key ?

`gpg --list-keys --batch --with-colons 2>&1 | grep pub | cut -d':' -f2`